# How can I insert an array of user ids into a Laravel 9.0 events table for use in a Flutter API?

Tags: sql, flutter, api, rest, laravel-9

**Laravel 9.0 inserting an array of values into another table**
I am trying to create a public event from events table and that event has many users associated with it from the users table.
How can I save the user data into the event as an array of user ids so that I can retrieve them later in my API that been consumed by flutter app.

I am expecting a method or a relationship between the two tables so that when I call events table I can also get the users data associated with that event.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, you can achieve this by defining a many-to-many relationship between the events table and the users table using an intermediate table. Here's how you can set it up:

1. Create a migration to create the intermediate table:

```bash
php artisan make:migration create_event_user_table
```

2. In the generated migration file, define the necessary columns:

```php
Schema::create('event_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('event_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->timestamps();

    
    $table->foreignId('event_id')
          ->constrained()
          ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreignId('user_id')
          ->constrained()
          ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

3. Run the migration to create the intermediate table:

```bash
php artisan migrate
```

4. In your `Event` model, define the relationship with users:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Event extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

5. In your `User` model, define the relationship with events:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class);
    }
}
```

Now, you can associate multiple users with an event by adding their IDs to an array and saving it:

```php
$event = new Event();
$event->name = 'Public Event';
$event->save();

$userIds = [1, 2, 3]; // Array of user IDs

$event->users()->sync($userIds);
```

This code will create a new event in the events table and associate the specified user IDs with it in the intermediate table.

To retrieve the users associated with an event, you can simply access the `users` relationship on the event object:

```php
$event = Event::find(1); // Retrieve the event with ID 1
$users = $event->users; // Retrieve the associated users
```

In your API, you can serialize the event and include the users' data to send it to your Flutter app.